# AWK - Substraction of a number after a keyphrase

Tags: awk, scripting, yaml

I have a file where a pattern string repeats like `ABC:10`, what I'm looking for it's every time in the file there is this `ABC:10` must always transform it into `XYZ:5`

The trick part is that the number part, e.g. 10, it's based on time, so every time I download the file it changes, so we can consider `X` the number:
`ABC:X` -> `XYZ:(X-5)`.

In the file the number is always the same, but when I re-download the file it changes based on a time schedule.
Also it's critical that identing cannot be lost.

For the below file example basically every time i see 等级3剩:58.1天 i need to modify the 等级3剩 -> DATA and 58.1-> 28.1 (X-30).
The 等级3剩 will always be the same each time i download the file but the number is basically the remaining days, so each day passes it will go down 1.

File Example:

```
port: 6666
socks-port: 6699
redir-port: 6669
allow-lan: true
mode: Rule
log-level: info
external-controller: 0.0.0.0:9090

dns:
  enable: true
  ipv6: false
  # listen: 0.0.0.0:53
  # enhanced-mode: fake-ip
  nameserver:
    - 223.5.5.5
    - 114.114.114.114
  #  - 'tls://dns.rubyfish.cn:853'
  #fallback:
  #  - 'tcp://208.67.222.222:443'
  #  - 'tls://1.0.0.1:853'
  #  - 8.8.8.8
proxies:
  - type: ss
    server: test.com
    port: 49679
    password: test.com
    cipher: aes-128-gcm
    name: ♥流量:300.93GB 等级3剩:57.8天

proxy-groups:

  - name: Auto
    type: url-test
    proxies:
    - ♥流量:300.93GB 等级3剩:57.8天
   
    url: http://captive.apple.com
    interval: 600
  - name: ⏲fallback
    type: fallback
    proxies: 
    - ♥流量:300.93GB 等级3剩:57.8天
   
    url: http://captive.apple.com
    interval: 600
  - name: Proxy
    type: select
    proxies:
    - Auto
    - ⏲fallback
    - DIRECT
    - ♥流量:300.93GB 等级3剩:57.8天
  - name: Netflix等国外流媒体
    type: select
    proxies:
    - Proxy
    - DIRECT
    - ♥流量:300.93GB 等级3剩:57.8天
    
  - name: 爱奇艺等国内流媒体
    type: select
    proxies:
    - DIRECT
    - Proxy
    - ♥流量:300.93GB 等级3剩:57.8天
 
- GEOIP,CN,国内网站或资源
- MATCH,其它规则外
```

Comment: This seems to do the trick, do you have a guide where i can learn about awk?

Comment: I re-edit my previous answer (with some details), there are many tutorial arround there https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html (you can also browse `awk`tagged question here)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
awk -v days=30 '/等级3剩/ { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)  
     if ( $i ~ /等级3剩:/ ) { split($i,A,":") ; $i = "DATA:" A[2]-days "天" ;}}
     {print;}'
```

where

- `/等级3剩/` select line with "等级3剩"
- `for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)   if ( $i ~ /等级3剩:/ )` loop on argument looking fo pattern
- `split($i,A,":")` split pattern on ":" in A[1] and A[2] (in this case)
- `$i = "DATA:" A[2]-days "天" ;` adjust value
- `{ print }` print everything (wheter line was modified or not)

please note

- I put program on multi ligne for clarity, you can one line.
- I use `-v days=30` so you can use external variable if need be (e.g. `-v days=$DAYS` )
- As mentioned in comment identing seems to be lost:

  ```
    - name: Netflix等国外流媒体
       type: select
       proxies:
       - Proxy
       - DIRECT
   - ♥流量:302.75GB DATA:28.1天
   - name: Proxy
       type: select
       proxies:
       - DIRECT
   - ♥流量:302.75GB DATA:28.1天
   proxies:
     - type: ss
       server: zhs.fun
       port: 49679
       password: zhshi.gitlab.io
       cipher: aes-128-gcm
   name: ♥流量:302.75GB DATA:28.1天
  ```
- to overcome indentation problem, just generate `sed`'s instruction.

  ```
   awk -v days=30 '/等级3剩/ { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
    if ( $i ~ /等级3剩:/ ) { 
       split($i,A,":") ; 
       printf "s/%s/%s/\n",$i,"DATA:" A[2]-days "天"; exit ;}}' u |
    sed -f - u
  ```
- where `u` is your input file
- you can edit in place ( `sed -i` ) <s>but you need a copy of input data</s>

Comment: Problem is that identing  is lost, it's required to keep correct identing . Lucky on the same line it will only have once.

Comment: @Archemar I tried to go down that route (YAML parser), but it didn't like structure of the data.

Comment: I've edited the file example to the full one.

Comment: Thanks, seems like it's working! I'll try a few files to see the result.